# accessing a variable in another conroller via view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Ruby on Rails project, and I'm using ajax to update several parts on a page. I have a posts_controller that helps displays a set of posts. Each post has the ability to be 'hidden' and 'unhidden' through the hides_controller. In addition the page displays the number of posts shown. For example, when I load the page intially, it says "5 posts shown".

I've set up ajax to hide a post once the user selects to hide it; however, the view (rendered by the posts_controller) does not update the "5 posts shown" bit to "4 posts shown". I wrote the following ajax in the "`create.js.haml`" file, and thought it would solve it:

```
:plain
  $(".post#{@post.id}_container").hide("drop", { direction: "up" }, 'fast');  
  $(".post_counter").html("#{escape_javascript(render('users/posts/hide'))}");
```

users/posts/hide.html.haml:

```
%h6= "#{@posts.size} posts shown"
```

**The issue that I'm running into:** @posts is not defined in the 'hides_controller' 'create' action, instead it's defined in the 'posts_controller'. Obviously repeating the code does not make it very DRY.

Is there a way to tell the view to reference the variable from another controller? IE: find the @posts variable from the 'posts_controller' instead of the 'hides_controller'?

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Controller Structure:

```
**controllers (folder)**
  posts_controller.rb
  hides_controller.rb
  **users (folder)**
    posts_controller.rb
```

`posts_controller.rb` (in the parent [conrollers] folder):

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  code
end
```

`posts_controller.rb` (in child [user] folder):

```
class Users::PostsController < PostsController
  def update
    @posts is defined here
  end
end
```

hides_controller.rb:

```
class HidesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    code
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make hides_controller a subclass of posts_controller. i.e.

posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def create
   @posts = Post.all()
end
```

hides_controller.rb:

```
class HidesController < PostsController
def create
  super
  #whatever
end
```

So now @posts will available in your Hides views

UPDATE in response to your comment

I think you have several choices,  one is to not get too hung up on Dryness,  there is nothing preventing you from just repeating the @posts = ?  in the hides_controller.  Unless the  @posts = ? is rather complex.

Or,  you could just move the definition of @posts = ? up into top level posts_controller, if they are the same.

Or you can subclass hides_controller from Users::PostController,  and create a new action specific to loading @posts

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :loadposts, :only=>[:update]
  def loadposts
    @posts = ?
  end
end
class Users::PostsController < PostController
end
class HidesController < Users::PostsController
  before_filter :loadposts, :only=>[:create]
end
```

You can decide to run loadposts for any actions you want, i.e.

```
before_filter :loadposts, :only=>[:create,:update]
```

or

```
before_filter :loadposts , :except=>[:index,:new]
```

Comment: I like this, but my controller structure is a little different. Please reference the controller setup in my original post. Should I make the hides_controller a subclass of User::posts_controller? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Also, @posts is defined in the 'update' action, not in the 'create' action.